# Invalid Resx file. '\' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '<!--' or '<[CDATA['

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I was trying to put regular expression in Resx file which is an xml file.
But when I add the expressions, it is giving the following error.

```
Invalid Resx file. '\' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '<!--' or '<[CDATA['
```

The reg expression is

```
^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[\x20-\x7F]{1,35}(?<!\s)$
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding it manually in the text editor or through the RESX editor in Visual Studio?

Comment: I think `<` must be serialized as `&lt;`, but the best practice is to use CDATA blocks where you can use literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is an XML file, you need to encode special characters, i.e. `<` become `&lt;`, `>` becomes `&gt;` and `&` becomes `&amp;`.

So store it as:

`^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[\x20-\x7F]{1,35}(?&lt;!\s)$`

Answer (score 1):

The default Managed Resources Editor inside Visual Studio is able to escape every character for you. You should be able to copy your regex into it without problems.

If you then open your regex file in plain text you see something along those lines:

```
<data name="foo" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>^(?!\s)(?!.*\s\s)[\x20-\x7F]{1,35}(?&lt;!\s)$</value>
</data>
```